# Sensors to monitor elevation changes

Tags: rf, sensor

I am looking for a sensor that could accurately measure elevation changes from a static benchmark location to dynamic location. Ex boat dock is the benchmark and the boat is equipped with a sensor. If the lake rises 10 feet I want to be able to accurately calculate it from the elevation change from the boat to the dock.  Someone has suggested rf-tdr

Comment: While the boat is docked? Would measuring the depth of water do the trick?

Comment: A long pole with measurement marks can tell you the height of the water.  Lot's of places do that.  No electricity/battery required.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: You could compare a pressure sensor on the dock with one on the boat. What accuracy are you hoping for?

Comment: You can use an altimeter, it measures air pressure (altitude) as does a barometer. They measure the same thing but display it differently.  Your problem will be over time the air pressure changes so will your reference (assuming atmospheric pressure) and your calculated height. The question would be how will your calibrate your sensor.

Comment: GNSS is one method. Cost depends on accuracy required. You could use DGPS with the reference station on the dock and the mobile station on the boat. Centimeter precision is achievable.